# How to use Process class

Tags: php

How do I use the following class to launch a process?

```
<?php
/* An easy way to keep in track of external processes.
 * Ever wanted to execute a process in php, but you still wanted to have somewhat controll of the process ? Well.. This is a way of doing it.
 * @compability: Linux only. (Windows does not work).
 * @author: Peec
 */
class Process{
    private $pid;
    private $command;

    public function __construct($cl=false){
        if ($cl != false){
            $this->command = $cl;
            $this->runCom();
        }
    }
    private function runCom(){
        $command = 'nohup '.$this->command.' > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!';
        exec($command ,$op);
        $this->pid = (int)$op[0];
    }

    public function setPid($pid){
        $this->pid = $pid;
    }

    public function getPid(){
        return $this->pid;
    }

    public function status(){
        $command = 'ps -p '.$this->pid;
        exec($command,$op);
        if (!isset($op[1]))return false;
        else return true;
    }

    public function start(){
        if ($this->command != '')$this->runCom();
        else return true;
    }

    public function stop(){
        $command = 'kill '.$this->pid;
        exec($command);
        if ($this->status() == false)return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
```

The command I want to execute is:

```
cd /home/bot/bot-victory/ && nohup ./ghost++
```

And how do I use the class start, stop, and get the status of my process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can do:

```
$process = new Process('/home/bot/bot-victory/ghost++');
```

This will also start the process. Note, I've modified your command slightly, but it should work the same way (the Process class you linked already adds nohup to the command).

Stop:

```
$process->stop();
```

Status:

```
$process->status();
```

Comment: thanks so much, how about if i have more than one bot? ex: bot-victory && bot-lose

Comment: You'd want two process objects, say $process1 and $process2 or $victoryBotProcess and $loserBotProcess

Comment: one more question, if im stop $process->stop(); i just to $process->Start(); right? no need to make new Process();

Comment: You are correct, lowercase start though: $process->start();